# ProcessPoolExecutor not limiting to set value

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a number of computation processes that need to be ran. They take anywhere from 20 minutes to 1+ days. I want the user to be able to observe what each is doing through the standard output, therefore I am executing each in its own cmd window. When I set the number of workers, it does not observe that value and keeps on spinning up more and more until i cancel the program.

```
def run_job(args):

    os.system("start cmd /k \"{} > \"{}\\stdout.txt\"\"".format(run_command,
                                                            outpath))

  
CONCURRENCY_HANDLER = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = 3)
jobs =[]

ALL_RUNS_MATRIX = [{k1:v1...kn:vn},....
         {kA1,vA1...kAn,vAn}
                ]
with CONCURRENCY_HANDLER as executor:

    for idx, configuration in enumerate(ALL_RUNS_MATRIX):

        generate_run_specific_files(configuration,idx)

        args = [doesnt,matter]

        time.sleep(5)
        print("running new")

        jobs.append( executor.submit(run_job,args))

        time.sleep(10)
```

I Originally tried using the ThreadPoolExector to the same effect. Why is this not actually limiting the number happening concurrently, and if this wont work what should I use instead? I need to retain this "generate -> wait->run" path because of the nature of the program (I change a file that it reads for config, It starts, retains all necessary info in memory, then executes) so I am wary of the "workers pull their work off a queue as they come available" model

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code references `cf` and `_.NUM_CONCURRENT` but these are not defined within the code, and they are directly related to the issue. It would also be nice to see process table output while this code is running so that we can compare with `_.NUM_CONCURRENT`.

Comment: You are using a sub-process (from a process pool) to start a system command prompt to execute a command. But that system command prompt is already another process so using a process pool to do that does not seem to make much sense to me. I think a using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` made more sense. Why did you switch to a `ProcessPoolExecutor`?

Comment: To answer your question: As soon as the `start` command is satisfied by opening up the new command window, the `system` command returns as completed even though the run command being passed to `cmd /K` has only just started to run. Therefore the process in the pool is now free to run another task.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do. Maybe give us an example with a simple task that has the same issue with processes? Are you thinking of `max_workers` as an upper bound to the number of processes spawned? That might not be true. I think `max_workers` is the number of processor cores your process pool is allowed to use. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example),

> If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine. If max_workers is less than or equal to 0, then a ValueError will be raised. On Windows, max_workers must be less than or equal to 61. If it is not then ValueError will be raised. If max_workers is None, then the default chosen will be at most 61, even if more processors are available.

Here is a simple example,

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

futures = []


def job(i):
    print('Job started: ' + str(i))
    return i


def all_done():
    done = True
    for ft in futures:
        done = done and ft.done()
    return done


with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    for i in range(3):
        futures.append(executor.submit(job, i))
    while not all_done():
        sleep(0.1)
    for ft in futures:
        print('Job done: ' + str(ft.result()))
```

It prints,

```
Job started: 0
Job started: 1
Job started: 2
Job done: 0
Job done: 1
Job done: 2
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My main issue is that i want to limit the amount of "run_job"s that are active(not just executing) at one time. I originally thought  ThreadPool would do the trick but after reading the docs I found similar caveat to the ProcessPool you just mentioned.

Comment: I showed you how to do that in the code snippet. Only 3 jobs will be active there.

Comment: True, but doesn't quite fit my usecase. 
1. I have any number of configurations that I want to process, I want to complete them all, but at any point in time i only want to have N run_jobs working (and by extension N number of consoles displaying each jobs "progress").
2. I want to control the access to the configurations so only one may be spun up every 10 sec

As your code stands it would spin up all available jobs but distribute the 8 threads between them. I can control the flow with some loops and checks, but was hoping there were inbuilt structures to handle this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment as soon as the start command is satisfied by opening up the new command window, the system command returns as completed even though the run command being passed to `cmd /K` has only just started to run. Therefore the process in the pool is now free to run another task.

If I understand correctly your problem, you have the following goals:

1. Detect the true completion of your command so that you ensure that no more than 3 commands are running concurrently.
2. Collect the output of the command in a window that will remain open even after the command has completed. I infer this from your having used the /K switch when invoking `cmd`.

My solution would be to use windows created by `tkinter` to hold your output and to use `subprocess.Popen` to run your commands using argument *shell=True*. You can specify the additional argument *stdout=PIPE* to read the output from a command and funnel it the `tkinter` window. How to actually do that is the challenge.

I have not done `tkinter` programming before and perhaps someone with more experience could find a more direct method. It seems to me that the windows need to be created and written to in the main thread. To that end for every command that will be executed a window (a special subclass of `Tk` called `CmdWindow`) will be created and paired with the window command. The command and the output window number will be passed to a worker function `run_command` along with an instance of `queue.Queue`. `run_command` will then use `subprocess.Popen` to execute the command and for every line of output it reads from the output pipe, it will write a tuple to the queue with the values of the window number and the line to be written. The main thread is in a loop reading these tuples and writing the lines to the appropriate window. Because the main thread is occupied with writing command output, a special thread is used to create a thread pool and to submit all the commands that need to be run and to await for their completion. When all tasks are completed, a special "end" record is added to the queue signifying to the main thread that it can stop reading from the queue. A that point the main thread displays a 'Pausing for termination...' message and will not terminate until the user enters a carriage return at the console.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

class CmdWindow(Tk):
    """ A console window """

    def __init__(self, cmd):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(cmd)
        self.configure(background="#BAD0EF")
        title = Entry(self, relief=FLAT, bg="#BAD0EF", bd=0)
        title.pack(side=TOP)
        textArea = ScrolledText(self, height=24, width=120, bg="#FFFFFF", font=('consolas', '14'))
        textArea.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        textArea.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break") # read only
        self._textArea = textArea

    def write(self, s):
        """ write the next line of output """
        self._textArea.insert(END, s)
        self.update()

def run_command(q, cmd, win):
    """ run command cmd with output window win """

    # special "create window" command:
    q.put((win, None)) # create the window
    with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, text=True) as proc:
        for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
            # write line command:
            q.put((win, line))

def run_tasks(q, arguments):
    # we only need a thread pool since each command will be its own process:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        futures = []
        for win, cmd in arguments:
            futures.append(executor.submit(run_command, q, cmd, win))
        # each task doesn't currently return anything
        results = [future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)]
        q.put(None) # signify end

def main():
    q = Queue()
    # sample commands to execute (under Windows):
    cmds = ['dir *.py', 'dir *.html', 'dir *.txt', 'dir *.js', 'dir *.csv']
    # each command will get its own window for output:
    windows = list(cmds)
    # pair a command with a window number:
    arguments = enumerate(cmds)
    # create the thread for running the commands:
    thread = Thread(target=run_tasks, args=(q, arguments))
    # start the thread:
    thread.start()
    # wait for command output in main thread
    # output must be written from main thread
    while True:
        t = q.get() # get next tuple or special "end" record
        if t is None: # special end record?
            break # yes!
        # unpack tuple:
        win, line = t
        if line is None: # special create window command
            # use cmd as title and replace with actual window:
            windows[win] = CmdWindow(windows[win])
        else:
            windows[win].write(line)
    thread.join() # wait for run_jobs thread to end
    input('Pausing for termination...') # wait for user to be finished looking at windows

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I've updated the code. Instead of pre-creating invisible windows for each command, the window is only created when the command is kicked off.